# Git. What to do, when origin and local branch diverged and merge didnt go well?

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, cherry-pick

thank you for taking a minute to read this.
I only have basic knowledge of git and ran into a problem, i can't get my head around.
My remote origin (main) and local (main) diverged. New local changes were commited, but not yet pushed. In the meantime, remote origin also got some additional commits. I tried to merge remote main into local main, but altered some newer local files (older remote files altered newer local) by doing so, and ended up with a merged state I'd rather would not like to push to remote again.

```
Origin: a---b---c---d
             \       \
local :       e---f---Merge :(
```

- Is there a way i can push specific local commits to remote, so i have the missing local commits in remote, without breaking everything?
- Would a rebase have been the better solution in the first place? Any way to cleanup/undo?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Abort the merge, so that you're back to your unpushed, unmerged, commits on your local main, then create a proper branch and push that instead. Then afterwards you can reset your local main back to what the origin/main is. This will NOT solve your merge issue, but it will allow you to push your changes to the central repository, for instance if you want others to look into your merge issue for you. Note! If you're not familiar with git, you can and should make a complete copy of your local folder, so that if you mess up, you can always just restore from that backup.

Comment: What is wrong with the merge? What does it mean "it didn't go well"?

Comment: There is no way you can push your local main to the origins main, and keep your local changes, and the origin changes, without merging them. Rebasing have a tendency to produce *more* merge conflicts, not less, so I would assume this would not be helpful either.

Comment: In order for your local changes to main to be applied to the origins main, you need to complete that merge. You can undo the merge locally and start over, but you need to resolve the merge conflicts one way or another.

Comment: Seconding j6t's comment: what "did not go well"? What's wrong with the merge commit? You can always undo and redo it properly

Comment: Thank you for all your replies. My "problem" with the merge is for example, an older (remote) database script has been merged into a newer (local) database script. The newer has been previously updated and commited locally, but not yet pushed. I might be guilty of this and not checking twice before, but now i have a mashed up file :( One way would be an undo as @knittl suggested, but can i also push the specific missing commits to remote, that at least on remote a clean state would exist?

Comment: @itsrobotbob The commits cannot be missing, because they were merged and pushed. The commits exist. You can redo the merge and then copy the correctly resolve file content and commit this. Or you could just fix your file and make a new commit. The question is too vague to give a good, specific answer.